# Google Sheets: Query to sum different columns based on different WHERE clauses

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to Query a set of data and perform a lookup and sum on the same column or set of columns, using a different WHERE clauses for each result.

I know that question is not worded very well.  So here is the example.

This is a portion of the data set:

[image: Sample Data Set]

And here is the report I'm trying to build:

[image: Sample Report]

The QUERY function is in the cell under "Store Location" where the result Montana is currently.

It has a date picker to change the report parameters in the QUERY function:

[image: Date Picker]

Here is a link to this Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zgBVqeXeb_OG7CMzNzP8gXZOtiIsMbP9VRqSNDRQuNI/edit?usp=sharing

The problem is that the report needs to sum up column F based on the selected month for the "One Month" result, and also sum up 12 months worth of column F also based on the selected month.

The formula I have so far sums up 12 months correctly (using the WHERE clause) for one select parameter, but I don't know if a different WHERE clause can be applied to a different select parameter for the One Month result.  Here is my formula:

```
=QUERY('Sales Data'!A:I, 
"select A, 0, SUM(F)+0, 0+0, SUM(F), SUM(D)+SUM(E)+SUM(F)+SUM(G)
where A is not null
and H is not null
and H <= date '" & text($K$2, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'
and H >= date '" & text(date(YEAR($K$2), MONTH($K$2)-12, DAY($K$2)), "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'
GROUP BY A
order by SUM(F)+0 DESC
label A '', 0 '', SUM(F)+0 '', 0+0 '', SUM(F) '', SUM(D)+SUM(E)+SUM(F)+SUM(G) ''
",1)
```

The where clause that would apply to the One Month column would be:

```
and H = date '" & text($K$2, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'
```

And the "12 Month - % of Total Item Sales" would be more complex.

Note, the data set for each month only had dates of the 10th, so we can just use "=" for the One Month result.

Look at the notes on the report column titles in the Sheet for a description of what result goes there.

There is also an "Expected Result" tab in the Google Sheet.

I'm hoping to keep the solution a QUERY function if this kind of thing is possible, because I run into wanting to do this kind of thing often in Google Sheets.

I also know I butchered this question and it may not be clear.  Please forgive me.  Thank you!

Comment: You have to combine two `QUERY()` using array literal `{...}`. Your current formula doen's match your desired output for 12 months.

Comment: I see the direction you are headed.  But how do you make the results of the second and third QUERY sort (ORDER BY) in the same order as the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added solution to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zgBVqeXeb_OG7CMzNzP8gXZOtiIsMbP9VRqSNDRQuNI/edit#gid=2016300038). Its not `query` based by the way

```
=arrayformula(let(a,unique(filter('Sales Data'!A2:A,eomonth('Sales Data'!H2:H,)=eomonth(K2,))),
           b,map(a,lambda(z,sum(ifna(filter('Sales Data'!F:F,'Sales Data'!A:A=z,eomonth('Sales Data'!H:H,)=eomonth(K2,)))))),
           c,map(a,lambda(z,sum(ifna(filter('Sales Data'!F:F,'Sales Data'!A:A=z,eomonth('Sales Data'!H:H,)>edate(eomonth(K2,),-12),eomonth('Sales Data'!H:H,)<=eomonth(K2,)))))),
           d,map(a,lambda(z,sum(ifna(filter('Sales Data'!D:G,'Sales Data'!A:A=z,eomonth('Sales Data'!H:H,)>edate(eomonth(K2,),-12),eomonth('Sales Data'!H:H,)<=eomonth(K2,)))))),
     sort({a,if(len(a),iferror(1/0)),b,if(len(a),iferror(1/0)),c,to_percent(c/d)},3,0)))
```

[image]